# BigCommerce API to handle product styles

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using the BigCommerce API to create and update products.   I am trying to create several products that have several styles, and several colors per style.  For example, I may have something like a Christmas ornament.  It could have three sizes for the product, and then each size comes I red, green, and blue.

How would I create a product that has the same ID that would allow it?   Maybe an option set, with an embedded option set?   Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to ask that directly to BigCommerce.

Answer (score 1):

Create your product options/sets inside of Bigcommerce. Then apply the desired options when creating your products via the API. 
You can see how to do so in Bigcommerce documentation on the products resource. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products